# different browser's giving different output for a webpage

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website and i have designed a page but it is giving different results in chrome and firefox. The layout which i want, is giving correctly in chrome but firefox is giving different result..

I also want that all tables should start from top like in firefox they are appearing but chrome is not giving proper result

Please help me to get rid of this problem...I am attaching screen shots as:-
[image] in firefox
[image: Image in chrome]

In chrome

My html file code is as:

```
  <div id="page">
    <div class="container" >         
      <div style="overflow:hidden;">
            <table width="44%" >
            <tr>
            <th>Todays To-Do</th>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>T-shirts.xls</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Caps.xls</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Mugs.xls</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Pens.xls</td></tr>
            <tr><td>xxx</td></tr>
            <tr><td>xxx</td></tr>
            <tr><td>xxx</td></tr>
            </table>
            <table width="27%" >
            <tr>
            <th>Vendor Contact List</th>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>T-shirts.xls</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Caps.xls</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Mugs.xls</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Pens.xls</td></tr>
            <tr><td>xxx</td></tr>
            </table>
            <table width="27%">
            <tr>
            <th>Price list</th>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>T-shirts.xls</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Caps.xls</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Mugs.xls</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Pens.xls</td></tr>
            <tr><td>xxx</td></tr>
            </table>
            </br>
            </div>
            <table width="45.56%" >
            <tr>
            <th>Add new+</th>
            </tr>
            </table>
              </div>
           </div>
       </div>
```

My css including in this are as:

```
body 
{

     background: url(../images/bg-main.jpg)top repeat-x;
     text-align:left;
     color:#333;
     font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

   #maincontainer-02 
   {
       background:#ffffff;
       border-left:1px solid #dedede!important;
       border-right:1px solid #dedede!important;
       margin-top:5px;
   }

    table
    {
        display:inline;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0px;
    }

    td
    {
        border:solid 1px #bfbfbf;
    }

    th
    {
        background-color:#bfbfbf;
        border:solid 1px black;
        text-align:left;
        font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
        font-size:1.875em;
    }
    *
    {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #content
    {
        width:100%;
    }

    pre
    {
        border:3px solid #ccc;
        padding:5px;
        font-size:12px;
        font-family:arial;
    }
    .bold{font-weight:bold;}
    .blue{color:blue;}
    .red{color:red;}
```

and [there are its Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tusTD/)

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey used this css for reset your css file

```
    html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
    a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
    del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
    small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
    b, u, i, center,
    dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
    fieldset, form, label, legend,
    table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
    article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
    figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
    menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
    time, mark, audio, video, input[type="checkbox"] {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        font-size: 100%;
        font: inherit;
        vertical-align: baseline;
    }
    ol, ul {
        list-style: none;
    }
    img{
        border:0;
        outline:0;
        vertical-align:top;
    }
    a{
        outline:0;
        text-decoration:none;
        display:inline-block;
    }
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
    }
table tr td{
vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Thanks..i get the tables are aligning from top now...but can please tell me why ...the structure rendered in  firefox not in chrome??

Comment: because every browser some default properties and so than structure rendered . You can used css reset in every projects more in click here http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 0):

try adding a valign=top to your tables.

And in your CSS reset the browser defaults for HTML and body. Like this:

html, body { margin:0; padding:0 }